# OnClick Listener is not working (AppCompatActivity)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a default activity A. From Activity A i am loading Activity B.

In Activity B i have a button and a listener to button click event.
But, the button click event is not even firing.

When i use Activity B directly as Main activity everything works fine.

Can anyone help me on this?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginPresenter = new LoginPresenter();

    findViewById(R.id.btnLogin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginPresenter.onButtonClick(LoginActivity.this);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i have found the issue :) i made a mistake calling different activity at start

Answer (score 1):

I had been same issue for a 30 min.

Here is how I solved

1-

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```

to your activity

2-

```
BtnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
```

3-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.w(TAG, "on Click General");
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.BtnSend:

            break;
    }
}
```